# Pygame colliderect() function returning 0 (zeros) and 1 (ones) instead of True and False?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame2

`colliderect()` function won't return `True` and `False`; instead, it is returning `0` and `1`. When I use the function type it says `int` instead of `bool`. If I code using `0` and `1` instead of the boolean value the code works, but why is it happening? Pygame documentation doesn't mention anything about it.

```
def collisions():
    tileHitsList = []
    for rect in tileList:
        print(testcube.colliderect(rect)) #it weirdly prints 0 and 1 instead of False and True

        #tileList is a list which contains the rects of the tiles being rendering on the display
        #testcube is a rect that hits the tiles

        if testcube.colliderect(rect) == True:
            tileHitsList.append(rect)
    return tileHitsList
```

Comment: **True == value > 0 or value < 0** and **False == 0** so you are getting those results.

Comment: Found it weird cause the documentation doesn't mention anything about returning int values, I'll just use it like that  then, ty.

Comment: `if X == True:` is almost never the right thing to say, anyway.  Just use `if X:` (and likewise `if not X:` instead of an explicit comparison to `False`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's pretty normal if the pygame documentation didn't say anything about it, as `1` and `0` are very commonly used to replace `True` and `False`.

You can just do

```
if testcube.colliderect(rect):
   # Your code
```

without the `==`.

Here is a documentation on the matter: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-10